# When does the limit of sum(or product) of two functions not exist?

Tags: limits

If the limit of sum of two functions $f(x), g(x)$ exists and the individual limits do not exist then is it true that the only way this can happen is via cancellations of terms of the form $\frac{1}{h(x)}$ (that is $f(x)$ has $\frac{1}{h(x)}$ term and $g(x)$ has $-\frac{1}{h(x)}$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial function)? Is there any such known characterization for when the limits of sum of two functions $f(x), g(x)$ exists but individual limits may not exist? Here we consider non-trigonometric functions, Similarly for product, if the limit of product of two functions $f(x), g(x)$ exists and one individual limit does not exist can we conclude that $f(x) = \frac{1}{h(x)}\cdot h'(x)$ and $g(x) = h(x)\cdot g'(x)$ where $h'(x), g'(x)$ are polynomial functions?

Comment: Would you count something along the lines of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x + 1} - \sqrt{x},$ where the limits of the two individual functions go to infinity but the difference converges to $0$?

Comment: The truth can be much more unpredictable than this. The existence of a limit of $f(x)+g(x)$ or of $f(x)g(x)$ doesn't even imply that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are individually continuous anywhere, so there's no way we're going to be able to characterize them in terms of nice elementary functions.